# Processing: Trying to get face to change via mouse position

Tags: if-statement, processing

Basically what I'm trying to do is have the face change when I hover over it. Everything compiles but for some reason when the cursor is over it's coordinates the face remains the same. I'm not sure if this has something to do with not using setup or draw methods, but I still get the same problem when I add those in.

```java
size(600, 400);
background(49, 185, 232);
noStroke();
smooth(8);

//Loop that determines if face is scared or unsuspecting based off of mouse position.
if(mouseX>200 && mouseY<400)
{
//Scared Face
//Intializing head position data
  int headX=300;
  int headY=200;
  int headSize=200;
//Actual head rendering
  fill(255, 196, 77);
  ellipse(headX, headY, headSize, headSize);

//Intializing nose position data
  int noseTopX=300;
  int noseTopY=200;
  int noseLX=280;
  int noseLY=220;
  int noseRX=320;
  int noseRY=220;
//Rendering of nose
  fill(245, 74, 86);
  triangle(noseTopX, noseTopY, noseLX, noseLY, noseRX, noseRY);

//Intializing mouth position data
  int mouthLX=260;
  int mouthLY=250;
  int mouthRX=340;
  int mouthRY=250;
//Mouth Rendering
  stroke(1);
  strokeWeight(40);
  line(mouthLX, mouthLY, mouthRX, mouthRY);

//Getting rid of stroke
  noStroke();

//Initializing Left Eye position
  int eyeLX=250;
  int eyeLY=170;
  int eyeLSize1=75;
  int eyeLSize2=50;
  int pupilL=50;
//Initializing Left Eye 
  fill(250);
  ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, eyeLSize1, eyeLSize2);
  fill(1);
  ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, pupilL, pupilL);

//Initializing Right 
  int eyeRX=350;
  int eyeRY=170;
  int eyeRSize1=75;
  int eyeRSize2=50;
  int pupilR=30;
//Initializing Right Eye
  fill(250);
  ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, eyeRSize1, eyeRSize2);
  fill(1);
  ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, pupilR, pupilR);
}
else
{
//Unsuspected Face
//Intializing Head Data
  int headX=300;
  int headY=200;
  int headSize=200;
//Actual head rendering
  fill(255, 196, 77);
  ellipse(headX, headY, headSize, headSize);

//Intializing nose position data
  int noseTopX=300;
  int noseTopY=200;
  int noseLX=280;
  int noseLY=220;
  int noseRX=320;
  int noseRY=220;
//Rendering of nose
  fill(245, 74, 86);
  triangle(noseTopX, noseTopY, noseLX, noseLY, noseRX, noseRY);

//Intializing mouth position data
  int mouthLX=260;
  int mouthLY=250;
  int mouthRX=340;
  int mouthRY=250;
//Mouth Rendering
  stroke(1);
  strokeWeight(4);
  line(mouthLX, mouthLY, mouthRX, mouthRY);

//Getting rid of stroke
  noStroke();

//Initializing Left Eye position
  int eyeLX=250;
  int eyeLY=170;
  int eyeLSize1=45;
  int eyeLSize2=30;
  int pupilL=10;
//Initializing Left Eye 
  fill(250);
  ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, eyeLSize1, eyeLSize2);
  fill(1);
  ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, pupilL, pupilL);

//Initializing Right 
  int eyeRX=350;
  int eyeRY=170;
  int eyeRSize1=45;
  int eyeRSize2=30;
  int pupilR=10;
//Initializing Right Eye
  fill(250);
  ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, eyeRSize1, eyeRSize2);
  fill(1);
  ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, pupilR, pupilR);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Processing, if you want it to do stuff after the very first frame, you must include an explicit `draw()` method. Merely adding `setup()` and `draw()` to your code allows interactivity. Note that the areas for changing the face appear to be improperly coded, but perhaps it's as you intended.

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 400);
  background(49, 185, 232);
  noStroke();
  smooth(8);
}
void draw() {
  //Loop that determines if face is scared or unsuspecting based off of mouse position.
  if (mouseX>200 && mouseY<400)
  {
    //Scared Face
    //Intializing head position data
    int headX=300;
    int headY=200;
    int headSize=200;
    //Actual head rendering
    fill(255, 196, 77);
    ellipse(headX, headY, headSize, headSize);

    //Intializing nose position data
    int noseTopX=300;
    int noseTopY=200;
    int noseLX=280;
    int noseLY=220;
    int noseRX=320;
    int noseRY=220;
    //Rendering of nose
    fill(245, 74, 86);
    triangle(noseTopX, noseTopY, noseLX, noseLY, noseRX, noseRY);

    //Intializing mouth position data
    int mouthLX=260;
    int mouthLY=250;
    int mouthRX=340;
    int mouthRY=250;
    //Mouth Rendering
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(40);
    line(mouthLX, mouthLY, mouthRX, mouthRY);

    //Getting rid of stroke
    noStroke();

    //Initializing Left Eye position
    int eyeLX=250;
    int eyeLY=170;
    int eyeLSize1=75;
    int eyeLSize2=50;
    int pupilL=50;
    //Initializing Left Eye 
    fill(250);
    ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, eyeLSize1, eyeLSize2);
    fill(1);
    ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, pupilL, pupilL);

    //Initializing Right 
    int eyeRX=350;
    int eyeRY=170;
    int eyeRSize1=75;
    int eyeRSize2=50;
    int pupilR=30;
    //Initializing Right Eye
    fill(250);
    ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, eyeRSize1, eyeRSize2);
    fill(1);
    ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, pupilR, pupilR);
  }
  else
  {
    //Unsuspected Face
    //Intializing Head Data
    int headX=300;
    int headY=200;
    int headSize=200;
    //Actual head rendering
    fill(255, 196, 77);
    ellipse(headX, headY, headSize, headSize);

    //Intializing nose position data
    int noseTopX=300;
    int noseTopY=200;
    int noseLX=280;
    int noseLY=220;
    int noseRX=320;
    int noseRY=220;
    //Rendering of nose
    fill(245, 74, 86);
    triangle(noseTopX, noseTopY, noseLX, noseLY, noseRX, noseRY);

    //Intializing mouth position data
    int mouthLX=260;
    int mouthLY=250;
    int mouthRX=340;
    int mouthRY=250;
    //Mouth Rendering
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(4);
    line(mouthLX, mouthLY, mouthRX, mouthRY);

    //Getting rid of stroke
    noStroke();

    //Initializing Left Eye position
    int eyeLX=250;
    int eyeLY=170;
    int eyeLSize1=45;
    int eyeLSize2=30;
    int pupilL=10;
    //Initializing Left Eye 
    fill(250);
    ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, eyeLSize1, eyeLSize2);
    fill(1);
    ellipse(eyeLX, eyeLY, pupilL, pupilL);

    //Initializing Right 
    int eyeRX=350;
    int eyeRY=170;
    int eyeRSize1=45;
    int eyeRSize2=30;
    int pupilR=10;
    //Initializing Right Eye
    fill(250);
    ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, eyeRSize1, eyeRSize2);
    fill(1);
    ellipse(eyeRX, eyeRY, pupilR, pupilR);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this earlier, but I kept getting compiler errors.